# Does intrinsic curvature in a higher dimension mean that the lower dimensions also exhibit curvature?

Tags: gravity, spacetime, differential-geometry, curvature, spacetime-dimensions

If our universe has intrinsic curvature in a higher dimension, would that mean the 3 dimensions that we live in would be curved? and if so would the lower dimensions exhibit intrinsic or extrinsic curvature as a result of the curvature in the higher dimension.

A follow up question would be, could the lower dimensions have intrinsic curvature without exhibiting any extrinsic curvature in higher dimensions

Comment: what do you mean by the universe having intrinsic curvature "in a higher dimension"?

Comment: Our 3D universe exhibits intrinsic curvature, if our universe was 4D and it had intrinsic curvature would we be able to notice it in our 3d world

Comment: Given that you tagged this with general relativity, our universe *is* 4D - three spatial and one temporal dimension. I'm not quite following you.

Comment: 4 spatial i meant, I apologize if it’s the wrong tag feel free to move it or remove it

Comment: In that case you have to explain the idea here much more clearly - how exactly is the universe supposed to have more spatial dimensions than we perceive?

Comment: In principal the universe might be locally something like a cylinder where the 4 space-time time dimensions are 'straight' and something else is 'curved'. But what are the candidates for the 'rolled up' dimension?

Comment: Do you mean like our actual Universe? Curved 4D spacetime, with very nearly flat space at large scales.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A cylinder is a simple example which shows that curvature in one dimension does not imply curvature in another. We could imagine a universe which is (locally) flat in the 4 space-time dimension, but is curved in one or more other dimensions. These other dimensions could have a large or small amount of curvature, and in a SF context might be seen as 'like' space-time in some respect. In a Physics context though the difficult question is what they are. Is there anything we can measure or perceive which could be interpreted as a 'dimension' orthogonal to space-time?

Comment: that curvature in one dimension does not imply curvature in another- is this always the case?

Comment: Curvature in one dimension does not on its own imply curvature in another dimension. There would need to be other conditions linking the dimensions together.